# How to stop passing query parameters if the value is null. Using 'ng-attr-href'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-ng-if

I am new to Angular.
In my program, I am passing some values inside a `<a href>` tag.

The current code is this.

```
<a (click)="navigateFunction()" href="{{sceURL}}/?orderId={{orderId}}">
```

component.ts :

```
navigateFunction(){
    this.orderId = this.orderIdFormGroup.value.orderId;
    this.sceURL = "URL";
    }
```

If the value is null, it reloads with the key like this.

```
 URL/rtap-menu/gadget-rtap-sce?orderId=
```

How to change it into pass only URL is the value is **Null**
I hope it can be done using **ng-attr-href**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing

```
get gotoUrl() {
   return this.orderId 
        ? `${sceURL}/?orderId=${orderId}`
        : this.sceURL
}
```

and in html like

```
<a (click)="navigateFunction()" [href]="gotoUrl">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to angular, you should read on how routing works in this [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/router). In  particular, how routerLink works (which should be leveraged for internal navigation withing application) and how you can pass the parameters array, e.g.

```
<a [routerLink]="['orderId', orderIdFormGroup.value.orderId]">
```

This removes the need of the (click) listener and adds usability (since links will be correctly display and can be copied).